# Cryptographically Secure Pseudo-Random Number Generator in Qt/C++ (Cross platform)

Tags: c++, sql, qt, password-encryption

I am developing a secure application that manages sensitive data, so I need some sort of secure login mechanism. I'm using the Qt Libraries (C++ version), and so far I can't find a function that offers this [Cryptographically Secure Pseudo-Random Number Generator] to get a Salt when the user creates an account from my application. I am aware of how one should go about storing passwords in a database, and it seems that a CSPRNG is a must when making a new salt. I looked and looked for a long time trying to find a way to do this in Qt, but I've just about reached the conclusion that there isn't a way to do this in Qt alone. Rather, is there at **least** a cross platform, C++ approach to doing this? I'm okay with including a library, but I'd prefer it to be LGPL so if I choose to develop a proprietary/closed-source application in the future, I can still use the same method(s). Some additional information is that I'll mo t likely be using SQL (MSSQL Express servers) for now, so I'm adding the SQL Tag. I'm probably going to be using QSslSocket as well (for encryption between client/server) if that helps. If you could shed some light not this, I'd be most grateful!

Comment: You *don't* want to develop such a thing. You *do* want to use a well vetted one already in existence. Really. It's what Bruce would do.

Comment: boost has really nice rand libraries and so does C++11/C++0x which most compilers already have cross platform

Comment: @pyCthon a cryptographic PRNG has been requested here.  The PRNGs provided by the standard and by boost are not cryptographic.

Comment: I am surprised that *nobody* has pointed out just how wrong the poster's assumptions about salt are, but everybody rushed to give answers (some sensible, some not) instead of actually trying to educate the original poster.

Comment: @pyCthon, since MSSQL Express was mentioned in the question it seems that Linux shouldn't be assumed as the sole target platfrom.

Comment: @NikB. I think he is right. In doing some more research I realized that a salt is not what I thought it was. I'll probably just use a simple random number if this is the case. Thanks for all the quick answers though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you *think* you need a cryptographically secure PRNG for generating salts then I must tell you that you do not understand what the salt is and how and why it works and against which kinds of attacks it is useful.

The simple fact that the salt must be stored *in plaintext* alongside the hash of the salted password should have given away that you do not really need a cryptographically secure PRNG for salt - or any PRNG for that matter. Frankly, you could have a simple 64-bit number, which you increase by one every time you need a new salt and it would be just as secure as a salt generated by a cryptographically secure PRNG.

Comment: Oh wow. Really?! So this means I could, in theory, just use rand() and seed it with something random, like the time? I'm still new to the whole cryptography world. In all honesty, I was thinking the same thing when I realized salts were stored in plaintext in the tables on my database. However, CPRN's were brought up as the correct way to do this.

Comment: @Nik B. an incrementing salt is not as secure as one generated by a crypto PRNG.  For example an attacker who knows how many users a system and the hash algorithm used can still precompute the hash lookup tables from a password dictionary for all of the salts.  Considering that the purpose of salts is to prevent attackers from having sufficient information to precompute hash lookup tables using sequential salts removes much of the benefit of using salts.

Comment: I don't really see this as a big deal. However, if you are *really* concerned about this then the answer is simple: pick a random 64-bit salt once, set it as the starting salt, and then increment it by one every time you need a salt.

Comment: @Nik B. Alright, so now the attacker needs one more piece of data besides the algorithm and number of users, which is the start of the range (or the salt for any one user to calculate an approximate start of the range).  The big deal is that if you're mitigating security threat, why water down the mitigation just to make the implementation slightly easier rather than just using a crypto PRNG so that the range is as broad as possible and the ability to precommut hash look tables is maximally reduced.

Comment: @JoshHeitzman: Why add complexity when you have no reason to think it will provide any additional security?

Comment: @JoshHeitzman Your thinking is typical of many: "well, if any number will do, then a *random* number will do even better!" Alas, security doesn't work like that.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I do have reason to think it will provide additional security, as I just stated in the comment immediately above yours.

Comment: @NikB. You have incorrectly stated what my thinking is on this matter is.

Comment: @JoshHeitzman Let's assume you have a "perfect" 32-bit PRNG: it generates a random permutation of all possible 32-bit numbers. You use 32-bit salts and have approximately 4 billion users. I also have approximately 4 billion users, and use just an incrementing 32-bit salt starting from zero. Why is my security watered down and yours isn't? ;)

Comment: @NikB. your scenario proves my point, as is it is the extreme edge case required for incrementing salts to be as secure as crypto PRNG salts.  Considering 1) only a tiny number of systems even have the potential to have 4 billion users and the operators such systems should be able to afford to hire security experts who will not come to stackoverflow looking for help with salts, and 2) most systems only actually have a relatively (to 4B) small number of users , it is not clear what this scenario brings to the conversation.

Comment: *sigh* With an ideal RNG the sequence 1, 2, 3, 4 is just as likely as the sequence 74572878, 39134, 77, 438498114... The point of salting isn't to magically add security; it's to prevent amortizing the cost of a brute force attack across an entire database (or  across multiple database or even multiple sites). A salt - *ANY* salt - will do that, as long as it's unique.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19786/discussion-between-josh-heitzman-and-nik-b)

Answer (score 2):

The crypto library in OpenSSL has [rand](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/rand.html) functions that "implement a cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator (PRNG)."

OpenSSL has been around for over 10 years and is still being actively developed.

Here is the OpenSSL [license](http://www.openssl.org/source/license.html).

Comment: Okay, that looks great. However, is it worth using OpenSSL _just_ for generating a Salt? I have looked at Botan as well, which is specifically made for cryptography. It has been used (actively developed) in Qt, so I'd prefer to use this anyways. Not to mention that I will already be including it in my application. Has anyone had success using the included bcrypt to salt and hash passwords to be stored in a remote database?

Comment: Botan also provides a lot more than just crypto PRNGs so I'm not sure it makes much difference.  My impression is that OpenSSL is more widely used than Botan, but I don't have hard data.

Comment: Okay. However, I'm not familiar with OpenSSL and generating salts/hashes. Could you direct me to the correct documentation?

Answer (score 2):

The standard library provides `<random>` which includes `std::random_device`, intended to offer access to a non-deterministic RNG. It's not guaranteed to provide a cryptographic pRNG, so you'll have to checked the platforms you care about.

libc++ uses /dev/urandom by default, which is a crypto-pRNG on OS X (Yarrow) and Linux (which uses an entropy pool that can be depleted, you may wish to tell random_device to use "/dev/random" instead).

libstdc++ IIRC uses, depending on a macro, either "/dev/urandom" as well or is a deterministic pRNG.

VC++ as of VS2012 provides a non-deterministic `std::random_device`. Earlier versions are deterministic.

Due to the fact that some implementations of `random_device` are deterministic you may wish to use Boost's implementation of random_device instead. On linux and OS X it uses "/dev/urandom" by default, and on Windows it uses the cryptographic service provider "MS_DEF_PROV".